# Show that if $0 < α < β < \frac π2$, there is $θ$ such that $α < θ < β$ and $\frac{\cos β−\cos α}{\sin α−\sin β} = \tan θ$

Tags: trigonometry

Using transformation formula, we get $\tan\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\right)$. Don't know how to proceed further. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$a<\dfrac{a+b}2<b$$

Answer (score 3):

Here's a trigonographic demonstration:

[image]

$$\tan\theta = \frac{\cos\alpha - \cos\beta}{\sin\beta - \sin\alpha} \qquad \qquad 0 < \alpha < \theta < \beta < 90^\circ$$

Comment: Simply beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

you Need a more general form of the mean value Theorem:
$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(x_0)}{g'(x_0)}$$

Comment: Sir.. Cauchy's mean value theorem? Thank you Very much.